# Reference a generic value from a record

Tags: f#, record

The below is a sample of code which I am using to pull specific values, by name, from a record type:

```
let ExtractVal1 = // signature - 'seq<float[]>[]'
    projectCF // signature - 'seq<Records>[]'
    |> Array.Parallel.map (fun x ->
        x |> Seq.map (fun y -> y.Val1) // Val1 is one of the values in my record type
    )

let ExtractVal2 =
    projectCF 
    |> Array.Parallel.map(fun x->
        x |> Seq.map (fun y -> y.Val2) // Val2 is another one of the values in my record type
    )
```

The above works fine, but results in a lot of repetition (as I have to repeat this for each of the 5 values I wish to extract). What would be a lot cleaner is if could define a single function and pass the names of each value I want to extract to it. The below is an example of the kind of thing I would like to do (although this code clearly does not work):

```
let ExtractAnyVal (anyval: MyRecord.x) = 
    projectCF
    |> Array.Parallel.map (fun x->
        x |> Seq.map (fun y -> y.anyval)
    )

let ExtractVal1 = ExtractAnyVal val1
let ExtractVal2 = ExtractAnyVal val2
```

My question is, can I implement the above in F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why don't you just make the *accessor*-function a parameter like this:

```
let extract f = 
    projectCF 
    |> Array.Parallel.map (Seq.map f)
```

and use it like

```
let extractVal1 = extract (fun y -> y.Val1)
let extractVal2 = extract (fun y -> y.Val2)
```

**please note** I cannot test the code as you did not include enough information - so there might be some mistakes left

Comment: You are going to map the collection multiple times doing this, I would suggest demonstrating making a record to extract multiple properties into one result container, e.g. `type ExtractedData = {One : int; Two : string}` and `let results = extract  (fun y -> {One = y.Val1; Two = y.Val2})`.  Then you can extract multiple properties in one pass.  It might help to show how powerful the approach you suggest really is.

Comment: don't get me wrong but all the records are in memory anyway (and the parallel-map seems to be useless just to project out some values) - this is why I just answered the question without wondering to much ...

Comment: Yes, you're right but I suppose it could be reasonably used to pass a more simplified structure to an existing function which only required a subset of the original data.  I just worry about the size of the collection, the OP used `Array.Parallel.map` which wouldn't be worthwhile unless it were quite sizeable.

Comment: As it has a `seq` inside it will do nothing else but create a new array as the inner sequences are lazy